# BufferedReader readLine detect closed socket and use .ready()

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, bufferedreader, readline

Server snippet:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream())));
if (reader.ready()) {
    result = reader.readLine();
    if (result == null) {
         quit(); // handle closing the socket
    } else {
         // process result
    }
}
```

Client snippet:

```
BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "US-ASCII");
osw.write("hello\n");
osw.flush();
```

The problem:

When the client writes something to the server it gets read correctly but when the client closes it's socket (For example force quitting the program), the `reader.readLine()` should output `null`, because of `if (reader.ready()) {` the null result will never reach `quit()`.
if i leave away the `if (reader.ready()) {`, the server can't read data.

How do i fix this?

EDIT: i can't use a `while ((result = reader.readLine()) != null) {` because i need to run more code after that like this:

```
while (running) {
  try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream())));
    if (reader.ready()) {
      result = reader.readLine();
      if (result == null) quit();
      else // process result
    }
    catch (Exception e) { ... }

    // more code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself by running this piece of code every 5 seconds:

```
try {
          BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(thread_cnn.getOutputStream());
          OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "US-ASCII");
          osw.write("areyoustillthere\n");
          osw.flush();

} catch (Exception e) { 
           quit(); // handle quit if server can't reach client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ready() test. It is as simple as that. ready() is not a test for end of stream. readLine() will block while there is no data.

And you must create the BufferedReader once, outside the read loop. Otherwise you will lose data.

Comment: I don't want readline to block until this is data (further code will not be executed until there is data), that's why i have the `ready()` test.

Comment: Then you can never detect end of stream. But as you don't even have an 'else' for the 'if reader.ready()' test it is impossible to believe your statement. I think you have misunderstood something.